# TypeORM One-To-Many + Many-to-One Access Issue

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to add a `Person` to my NestJS app using TypeORM. I have declared a `Person` entity and an `Address` entity, with a One `Person` to Many `Address` relation. I am able to add the person and their address(es), but then when I try to access a person (or all of them) I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined
```

I'm not sure what is going on, as I followed [this example](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md) from the TypeORM docs for how to set up the ManyToOne and OneToMany relationship. I do notice, though, that the address table has the row in there, but the `personId` column is still `null`. You can see the `person.entity.ts` and `address.entity.ts` files, as well as the service that adds these items to the database, [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/pjlamb12/d4e4e98f199dae6cbfd3c6b1aecd569a).

Any tips to figure this out would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in [the line 30](https://gist.github.com/pjlamb12/d4e4e98f199dae6cbfd3c6b1aecd569a#file-person-entity-ts-L30) of `person.entity.ts`, where
`(address) => {address.person}` (you're returning `undefined` here)
should be
`(address) => address.person`